# Can I have an Enum of objects?

Tags: typescript, enums

I would like to define an enum (or type, i'm not sure if i've got the terminology correct) as being of a particular object, like so:

```
enum Notes {
  { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains list" },
  { subDir: "maps", desc: "file contains maps" },
}
```

I.e. an instance of type Notes, can only be of the following type, and with the above properties as defined in the enum:

```
interface Descriptor {
  subDir: string;
  desc: string;
}
```

Is this possible, either via using an enum or by some other methodology?

This is the closest i've got to achieving what I wanted, however I can't get the type itself to be seen as an instance of Descriptor:

```
type Notes =
  { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains lists" } |
  { subDir: "map", desc: "file contains maps" };

interface Descriptor {
  subDir: string;
  desc: string;
}
```

Comment: No, enum is the wrong construct / type to use here. I think you just want an array, maybe globally accessible, named Notes that contain one or more instances that conform to interface `Descriptor`

Comment: @Igor OK, can I accomplish it some other way instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, enum is the wrong construct / type to use here. I think you just want an array named `Notes` that contain one or more instances that conform to interface `Descriptor`

```
Notes: Descriptor[] = [
    { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains list" },
    { subDir: "maps", desc: "file contains maps" }];
```

Comment: thanks, how would I define Notes in that context within another interface? Specifically, an array of `Notes`, with each element corresponding to one of those Descriptor values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Notes` type is working for me in a larger interface:

```
type Notes =
  { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains lists" } |
  { subDir: "map", desc: "file contains maps" };

interface BiggerInterface { 
    notes: Notes[];
}
let b1: BiggerInterface = {
    notes: [  // OK
        { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains lists" },
        { subDir: "map", desc: "file contains maps" },
    ]
};
let b2: BiggerInterface = {
    notes: [  // error
        { subDir: "list", desc: "file contains something else" }
    ]
};
```

If this wasn't what you had in mind, please clarify the question.